# auto focus in nikon d7000

Tags: nikon, focus

I have a Nikon D7000. I am facing a problem. AF-S, AF-A, AF-C options are not showing in the camera monitor even after pushing the AF button and moving the dial. The different types of AF mode are not appearing. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What exposure mode do you have selected?

Comment: What lens is attached to the camera?